# Galton-Watson process : branching property

Tags: stochastic-processes

I can’t find a definition of the ‚branching property‘ of a Galton Watson process on the internet. Can someone help me, how it is defined or give me an example.

I have a branching processes book, but there is the ‚branching property‘ only for ‚lines‘ defined. I need it special for a Galton-Watson Process. :-)

I would be very thankful for that.

Kind regards!